# Fast exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, export

I have a table with around 2500 rows and 70 columns of simple data (yes/no). I would like to export this data to Excel file.

175000 cells doesn't look like really a lot, so I would expect it to export the data in up to 10 seconds.

What is the way to implement it?

P.S. I have tried EPPlus but it seems to be to slow (I accessed the cells one by one).

P. P. S. I would probably also like to use some styling (like to set bold text etc.). But it seems it's actually what slows done EPPlus exporting.

Comment: `CopyFromRecordset` should be good enough.

Comment: How much time did it take when you tried it?

Comment: A table where (MS SQL, Oracle, MySQL, Access, Dining room)?  What does the query to get the data out of the table look like?  Can you show the code you tried that was too slow?  How slow was it?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is OpenXML library. This is super fast and can do 175K cells in 10 seconds. You can also do custom formatting with this. It does not require excel to be installed either.

- Install Open XML SDK
- You can install the Open XML productivity tool and open an existing excel, this will generate C# code to export such an excel. This is useful to understand how the library works.

[Look here for examples](http://www.lateral8.com/articles/2010/3/5/openxml-sdk-20-export-a-datatable-to-excel.aspx) on using this open source Microsoft library.

I would suggest you use the SAX approach for maximum performance.